# Material-Table onRowClick waves animation; is this possible?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

I would like the Table Row on click to have a Material Waves animation across the entire row. At current it looks as though the closest thing I can get to is an On hover background change.

Does anyone know of the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding it looks like applying a Waves/Ripple animation will require an element to be added to the HTML DOM, which conflicts with how strict HTML5 is with table tags.

Since table tags cannot have children or wrappers, the easiest solution would be to utilize a material-ui list instead.

The downside of this approach of course is that I will have to implement searching and filtering columns, seeing as I can't leverage the material-table functionality.

I personally think that having proper button-like feedback on clicking a row is important, but for now I suppose a list will have to do.

If I'm incorrect in this prognosis, please let me know.